# A "mysterious" sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion, hypergeometric-function, pattern-recognition, elliptic-integrals

A [recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4324306/asymptotic-expansion-of-exp-left-pi-frac-2f-1-frac12-frac12-1-1-x/4324332#4324332) asked for the Taylor expansion of
$$f(x)=\exp\left(-\pi\,\frac {_2F_1(\frac12, \frac12, 1; 1-x)}{_2F_1(\frac12, \frac12;1;x)}\right)=\exp\left(-\pi\,\frac{K(1-x)}{K(x)}\right)=\frac{x}{16} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {a_n} {2^{b_n}}\,x^n$$
The numerators $a_n$ correspond to [sequence $A002639$ in $OEIS$](https://oeis.org/A002639). According to Jean-François Alcover's comment, $f(x)$ is the Taylor expansion of the $EllipticNomeQ(x)$ function in Mathematica (it gives the nome $q$ corresponding to the parameter $x$ in an elliptic function. In fact, the first terms of $f(x)$ are given [here](https://functions.wolfram.com/EllipticFunctions/EllipticNomeQ/06/01/02/).

The $b_{2n}$ make the sequence
$$\color{blue}{\{0,6,15,21,32,38,47,53,64,70,79,85,93,99,109,115,128,134,143,149,159,165,174,180,192
   ,198\}}$$ and  $b_{2n+1}=b_{2n}+1$.

The only thing I noticed is a pattern for $c_n=8n- b_{2n}$
$$\{0,2,1,3,0,2,1,3,0,2,1,3,3,5,3,5,0,2,1,3,1,3,2,4,0,2\}$$

> My question is : what are the $b_n$ corresponding to ?

Comment: It appears that $b_{4n+2} = b_{4n} + 6$

Comment: The sequence $b_{4n} - b_{4n-2}$ appears to be $\{9, 11, 9, 11, 9, 8, 10, 13, 9\}$ which doesn't mean much to me.